# Aurelia .NET Core - Browser sync not working on .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, aurelia

I followed [this](http://mobilemancer.com/2016/10/19/aurelia-spa-typescript-dotnet-core/) tutorial on how to use Aurelia/Aurelia CLI with .NET Core.

Changes that I had to make:

- Had to target a specific version for Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools, (**dotnet watch run command didn't work**)
- Changed aurelia.json => build => targets => output value from "." to "wwwroot/scripts", (**port:9000 didn't work**, errormessage: "Cannot GET / to the server", port 5000 served by .NET Core worked however).
- tasks => run.js => browsersync => server => basedir value from ['.'] to ['./wwwroot'], (**Fixed browser sync not working on port:9000**, however still doesn't work on port:5000 served by .NET Core)

**1. How can I make the Browser sync work on port:5000 served by .NET Core?**

It must be something in the run.js file. I have tried:

```
let serve = gulp.series(
  build,
  done => {
    browserSync({
        open: false,
        port: 9000,
        logLevel: 'silent',
        proxy: {
        target: 'localhost:5000'
      }
      }, function(err, bs) {
        let urls = bs.options.get('urls').toJS();
        console.log(`Application Available At: ${urls.local}`);
        console.log(`BrowserSync Available At: ${urls.ui}`);
        done();
    });
  }
);
```

..with no success..

**2. Does it matter if I develop on port:5000 or port:9000?**

**3. What's the point in hosting Aurelia in .NET Core?
Should I only use .NET Core for WepAPI etc?**

Comment: I sent a message to the author of that blog post asking him to take a look at this question. Hopefully we'll hear back from him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going about this in a very unorthodox way.

1. Just keep going with what you have. The standard is to host the .NET Core project on port 5000 and Browser Sync on port 9000.
   You can't host the .NET Core project and the Browser sync on the same port, and messing with the .NET Core project just to move Browser sync to port 5000 is just a lot of work for no benefit.
2. You develop an Aurelia application, whatever port you decide to host it on doesn't matter at all :)
3. I wanted to offer an alternative as most tutorials focus on developing on Node. Also, I personally like the MSFT ecosystem, and when I'm going live with any site, it's in Azure. So for me it makes more sense.

I recommend you use whatever technology that makes you productive and whatever makes sense regards to your choice of production environment.

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask! In your example you have one Aurelia project and one WebAPI project. Won't that cause problems when you publish to Azure? Wouldn't you need to have them both published? Is it not better to merge those two projects? CORS difficulties aswell? Thanks

Comment: Yes, yes, not necessarily and yes!

The setup will cause problems, and and solving them was the point. It was at least from a few versions of browsers back an issue with the Fetch implementation, so that was a good find early for those who need that kind of project. CORS was an issue too, but that gave us an opportunity to look at that and fix it in the setup of the .NET Core projects.

As for having to publish them together - no need. Most often you will work against just a pure API, whatever kind of project you are implementing.
But if you are developing a small project, then no need.

Comment: I got a late question for you if you dont mind:) In your tutorial you mention that the API shouldn’t be hosted in the same project as the SPA. Why is that? I don't see why that is a bad practice..

Comment: It depends on the size of the project, how you intend to host it, how many teams are involved etc. If it's just a small one man project, then no worries.
But for larger applications, IMHO, it's best to decouple the Web project and the API as much as possible. This will give you a number of benefits and just become more useful as your application/API grows.